# Android httpclient request and processing with entity

Tags: android, google-maps, httpclient

I do requests to my servlet

```
try {
                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG_MAPS, "try");

                HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
                post.setEntity(entity);

                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 150000);

                httpclient  = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                BasicHttpResponse  response = (BasicHttpResponse ) httpclient.execute(post);
                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG_MAPS, "http status code : "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                    Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG_MAPS, "response 200");
                    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                    if (responseEntity!= null) {
                        Gson g = new Gson();

                        InputStream is = responseEntity.getContent();
                        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

                        try{
                            responseEntity.getContent();
                            String x = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }

                        responseJSONObject = g.fromJson(reader, JSONResponseObject.class);
                        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG_TAG_MAPS_console, responseJSONObject.toString());
                        reader.close();
                        System.gc();    
                    }

                }   


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

/code>
```

and on line :

InputStream is = responseEntity.getContent();

app is crashing ...response code is 200 ...
I have looked on my tomcat logs and everything is ok. JSONResponseObject is filled with values and sended.

What could be the problem? How can I get stacktrace to logcat?

One maybe related problem: 
I have well know "Couldn't et connection factory client" in logcat
Any of thing could causing that issue is not my case

1. api key is correct, path to correct debug.keystore
2. all permissions in manifest
3. uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps in manifest as well

Map is displayed correctly, refreshing on zooming/moving.

Comment: stacktrace should be in logcat. Might be "System.err" as log tag. + `entity != null` should be checking `responseEntity`

Comment: How does it crash? there must be a some exception stack trace in Logcat. please post the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after anotate json objects with google.gson.annotations instead of just implementing serializable.